# OSX Open Atom from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I am trying to implement my own [dotfiles](https://github.com/agusgambina/dotfiles). I am using zsh as my default shell. When I try to launch Atom from terminal I get this error

> FSPathMakeRef(/Users/agusgambina/Applications/Atom.app) failed with error -43.

To start the application I am executing in the terminal

```
$ atom .
```

I am not sure what I have changed that broke this, but everything else that is similar seems to be working.

Thank you

Comment: How do you launch Atom? i.e. the full command you use

Comment: `fnfErr                        = -43,  /*File not found*/` - How are you attempting to start this bundled application?

Comment: @fd0 thank you for your quick answer I just wrote it in the post

Comment: @agusgambina -Well, I'm not going to go thru your dozen or more dot files. I'd say that the . `dot` after the atom command is not interpreted by the shell as a valid path.

Comment: @fd0 Thank you for your answers, I realised that was my mistake, I was overwriting the ATOM path and that was my mistake. I will delete the question since I think has no point because was a silly mistake of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exact question has been answered on SO.

With Atom open, select from the Menu Bar:

```
Atom > Install Shell Commands
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23666354/4581844